# .format() and unicode strings

Tags: python, unicode, format

i am trying to format a bunch of strings in python 2.7.6.
Everything works properly until an unicode sign shows up.
This short example shows my problem:

```
    a = 'ö'
    b = 'd'
    c = 'e'

    print('{:2}{:2}{:2}').format(a, b, c)
```

The result is:

öd e

But it should be:

ö d e

Tried a lot of stuff with encoding, decoding, unicodedata.normalize, but nothing seems to work.
Anyone got an idea what i am doing wrong?
Thanks for help and please excuse for my bad english.
Greetz,

BigZ

Comment: I bet this has something to do with the fact that `len(a)` is 2, even though it looks like it's only one character long.

Comment: Works fine for me on 2.7.6 - note that your parentheses are a bit wayward, but don't really change the syntax.

Comment: Decoding the letter into utf-8 will make len(a) show a length of 1, but if i try this in my code it throws an UnicodeDecodeError if an unicode sign shows up :/

Comment: Just discovered that im using 2.7.6 too 0:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do the trick for you?

```
>>> a = 'ö'
>>> b = 'd'
>>> c = 'e'
>>> print(u'{:2}{:2}{:2}'.format(a.decode('utf8'), b, c))
ö d e
```

This assumes that your data is utf8 encoded. Note that the format string is unicode.

Also, this doesn't seem to be a problem in Python 3.

Comment: Nope, sorry. This works fine in the example, but in my code it throws a UnicodeDecode Exception. :/

Comment: @BigZ You have a fundamental problem in that you're storing encoded data as bytes and wanting Python to know what it is.

Comment: So how do i get python to store my encoded data as strings?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what you're doing, but you'll want to use `unicode` for text.

Comment: Just discovered that im getting unicode and strings in my code, while parsing html and printing the results... -.-
Is there a way to unify everything?

Comment: You need to determine the encoding of the HTML that you are downloading, then convert that to unicode. Probably the encoding of the HTML is not UTF8. You might be able to tell by inspecting the charset in the HTML <meta> tag, e.g. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`. Or you could use the [`chardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) module to see if it can figure out the encoding. Or you could post the URL and someone will pretty quickly be able to tell you.

Comment: Thx, your answer above solved the problem.
Didn't saw that i need to convert my string to unicode with u'{:2}{:2}{:2}' while printing it.